# SEO url for multi-language site

Tags: seo

Are the following urls threated the same in SEO rank or is someone better than another? If, why?

- `language.example.com/page`
- `example.com/language/page`

Comment: Happy you liked it!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting article on that matter:

http://seotech.wordpress.com/2008/06/06/technical-seo-issues-sub-domain-sub-directory/

You should decide which is best regarding its content, but the language in particualar to show you an example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page

Before the domain seams to be the standard and I would recommend it!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Google just announced [New markup for multilingual content](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html). This should make it easier for multi-language sites to deal with translated versions of their website.